# Fetching an Image through a viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

Is it possible to fetch an image and to store it in an ImageView from a viewPager using a particular position?
I tried to store in bitmap using drawableCache(), but it didn't help me.

Comment: Yes using _viewpager.setCurrentItem(position)_

Comment: @Piyush I'm asking to fetch the image from ViewPager from any of the position. I'm not asking to set image at Current Position.

Comment: `ViewPager` does not store all views at once. It stores current page + 1 to the left + one to the right (by default). Therefore, you need to switch to desired page first, and then you should be able to get drawing cache of whole VIewPager.